# login automatically with javascript field fill and submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

We have a local https page for login. I want to load it from outside in an iframe and put username and password inside it then submit these two info with javascript . (auto login). I mean i want the page to be logged in automatically (automatically fill the username and password then submit info on page open)
here is the code that i used

```
<iframe src='https://xxxxxx/login.html' name='login' id='login'></iframe>
<script language="javascript>


  parent.login.formname.username.value = 'username';
parent.login.formname.password.value = 'pass';
parent.login.formname.submit();
window.frames['login'].document.formname.submit();
</script>
```

I saved the code in a HTML FILE AND WHEN I OPEN IT NOTHING HAPPENS.
note that i can open the https page in my iframe
what should i do?
is there better approach?

Comment: under the different domain (even sub-domain) issue, JS will not allowed cross-domain to access any element by this policy.

Comment: Why are you using an iframe to do this?

Comment: @Maurice i guess thats the only possible solution,is there other practical solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify content of iframe with javascripts or without user involvement because of same origin policy. If your iframe directory and your iframe "showing" domain is same, then however, you can do so.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach would be a json that pass on username and a special ID (NOT PASSWORD, it's insecure)
The special ID could be generated everytime you log in by using random characters/current time / etc. May also be an even better approach, but this WORKS and is SAFER :)
Get this page by the ID, not the username.